# файловый дескриптор

Tags: linux

Почему команды:
ps -U 5> user_5_ps , ps -U 555> user_5_ps, ps -U > user_5_ps и ps -U
Возвращают одинаковую ошибку: "error: list of real users must follow -U"
А команда ps -U 5555> user_5_ps обычно возвращает другую ошибку: “bash: 5555: Bad file descriptor”

Comment: Потому что вы перед `>` не поставили пробел и в итоге получили что попало

Comment: в первых командах тоже нет пробела, но выводит отсутствие реального юзера...

Comment: Нет, он выводит отсутствие значения для аргумента `-U`, потому что ваша пятёрка без пробела становится не номером пользователя, а номером перенаправляемого файлового дескриптора

Comment: то есть 5555 дескриптора не существует ? а остальные существуют 5 , 555

Comment: По умолчанию в линуксе ограничение на 1024 файловых дескриптора, но его можно увеличить через `ulimit -n` (только в этом нет никакого смысла, потому что `ps` всё равно не будет использовать эти дескрипторы)

Comment: окей , спасибо.